# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'file.txt' -> 'symlink.txt' while using os.symlink

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am using `helm charts` to deploy my kubernetes application in local cluster `minikube`. I was able to mount `/home/$USER/log` directory and verified by creating and modifying file in the mounted directory using shell command.

```
#touch /log/a
# ls
a  delete.cpp  dm
```

But when I am using python to create symlink it is failing.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.symlink("delete.cpp", "b")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'delete.cpp' -> 'b'
```

Any idea why symlink is not working. 
**I am able to use same code in different directory**

To mount host directory in minikube I am using

```
minikube mount ~/log:/log
```

My deployment script looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: log-dir
        hostPath:
            path: /log
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-image
        imagePullPolicy: never #It's local image
        volumeMounts:
        - name: log-dir
          mountPath: /log
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "./my_app_executing_symlink" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Linux manpage on `symlink(2)`, you'd get that error when the file system doesn't support symlinks.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html)

```
   EPERM  The filesystem containing linkpath does not support the
          creation of symbolic links.
```

In the case of a `minikube` mount, that certainly sounds possible.

Comment: Is there any way to provide necessary permission while mounting directory to `minikube` followed by container

Comment: I've never used Minikube, but things probably rely on which mount driver you happen to be using; see https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/ maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minikube, you can use [`hostpath` persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume) that [supports hostPath](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/) for development and testing on a single-node cluster.

Example usage:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/log"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: example-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: pv0001
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: example-volume
  containers:
    - name: my-app
      image: alpine
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 10000" ]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: pv0001
          mountPath: /log
```

After successful deployment you will be able to create symlinks in `/log` directory:

```
$ kubectl exec -it my-app -- /bin/sh
/log # touch a
/log # ln -s a pd
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 25 17:49 a
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             1 Nov 25 17:49 pd -> a
```

And as mentioned in documentation:

> minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following
> directories, which are made in the Minikube VM (or on your localhost
> if running on bare metal). You may lose data from other directories on
> reboots.

- /data
- /var/lib/minikube
- /var/lib/docker
- /tmp/hostpath_pv
- /tmp/hostpath-provisioner